# How to clear all the textbox fields in a parent page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is their any way to clear all the textbox values in a parent form using jquery or javascript.
Now i am clearing each fields using

```
var parentDoc1 = window.opener.document;
parentDoc1.getElementById(id).value="";
```

Comment: `$(parentDoc1).find('input[type=text]').val('')` ?

Comment: @Engineer ...It is working fine

Comment: Do u konw how to escape some textboxes?

Comment: what do you mean by 'escape'?...exclude?

Comment: Yes i want exclude some textboxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear the *all* textboxes , you can use this:

```
$(parentDoc1).find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

If some of textboxes (e.g. textboxes with `mytextboxclass` class, with `mytextboxid` id,etc...) mustn't be cleaned, then you can use `:not` in your selector for excluding those:

```
$(parentDoc1).find('input[type=text]:not(.mytextboxclass,#mytextboxid)').val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this also

```
$('input:text').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `class` in all the input field....

try this..

```
 $('input.className').val('');
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9VxaD/1/)

OR

this but this puts the value as empty to all the inputfield in the document

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('');
```

Comment: $('.classname') has to search the entire dom!  $('input.classname') would be better

Answer (score 0):

How about this to clear all text boxes:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

This clears the values of all text areas which are in parent with id `parent`.

```
$('#parent').children('textarea').val('');
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/Y2t7x/1/

Important thing is that the script clears only the text areas which are direct siblings of `#parent`, not nested ones.

If you want to reset the values of text areas which are among siblings of the parent too you should replace `children` with `find`.

If you want the script to work with text inputs use:

```
$('#parent').children('input[type=text]').val('');
```

or

```
$('#parent').find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Again depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to select the content of a page in an other tab/window? or do you want to get the parent-page-content cause your context is that you are inside an iframe? if it's the last, don't use

```
window.opener.document;
```

use following instead

```
window.parent.document;
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you're using jQuery anyway, you can just use .reset() instead of .val('').

Answer (score 0):

you can also create function on parent window and call it from child window.
In child window call parent function as below.

```
<script>
function ClearFromChild(ARGS)
{
    window.opener.clearinparent(ARGS);
}
</script>
```

now just declare `clearinparent` function in parent window and you are done.
Cheers,